# Getting 'Nothing' (or 'Null' in C#) in WebControls in Code-Behind file in ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an `aspx` page (say `MyPage.aspx`) where a part of it has the following structure -

```
<asp:DataList ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server" ...>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" ...>
            <asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" ...>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I added the `asp:Panel` element and the `asp:Button`s to it manually (wrote them physically) to the page which I got as a part of some project. I also added the definitions of these controls to the `MyPage.aspx.vb` in `MyPage` class -

```
Protected WithEvents panel As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel
Protected WithEvents button1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
Protected WithEvents button2 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
```

Now, I'm able to access elements in the `vb` file and the elements are getting rendered (visible in browser) too but in code-behind file I get `Nothing` in all 3 of them so I get `NullReferenceException` when I try to access their properties. (There is no `MyPage.aspx.designer.vb` file)

I'm unable to figure out why is that. Kindly, help.

Thanks.

Comment: Those control references are null because the controls are inside an `<ItemTemplate>`, and for good reason: The DataList will instantiate your panel and buttons multiple times, once per item in your data source, so which of those controls would your references refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Liu points out in his comment, the buttons do not exist outside the scope of the DataList.

If you want to access those buttons you'll have to use some other methods like the `OnItemDataBound` event.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
```

Code behind

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    //find the button in the datalist item object and cast it back to one
    Button button = e.Item.FindControl("Button1") as Button;

    //you can now access it's properties
    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

VB

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataListItemEventArgs)
    'find the button in the datalist item object and cast it back to one
    Dim button As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("Button1"),Button)

    'you can now access it's properties
    button.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```

Or access it directly by item index after databinding

```
Button button = DataList1.Items[3].FindControl("Button1") as Button;
button.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

VB

```
Dim button As Button = CType(DataList1.Items(3).FindControl("Button1"),Button)
button.BackColor = Color.Green
```